# Query with HAVING clause is taking too long

Tags: mysql, mysql-8.0

I have query like this:

```
SELECT  msg.id, CONTENTS, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(msg.created_at) 'created_at',
        category, msg.`uid`,name, user_name, profile_pic, STATUS,
        isNotificationOn, onesignal_id, email, gender, phone,
        users.id userId, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(users.createdAt) 'createdAt',
        ( SELECT  COUNT(1)
            FROM  message_likes
            WHERE  uid = '006GA968vpb0O62xaOpKLuhR1cC3'
              AND  message_id = msg.id
        ) AS isLiked, 
        ( SELECT  COUNT(*)
            FROM  follower_list
            WHERE  follower_uid = '006GA968vpb0O62xaOpKLuhR1cC3'
              AND  following_uid = msg.uid) AS isFollowing,
        COUNT(DISTINCT share.uid) + msg.shares 'shares',
        COUNT(DISTINCT likes.uid) 'likes',
        msg.`application`,
        `isModified`, `modificationReason`, `isVoilation`, `voilationReason`,
        `followers_count`, `following_count`
    FROM  user_messages msg
    JOIN  users  ON msg.uid = users.uid
    LEFT JOIN  message_shares SHARE  ON msg.id = share.message_id
    left JOIN  message_likes likes   ON msg.id = likes.message_id
    LEFT JOIN  followers_count  ON msg.uid = followers_count.following_uid
    LEFT JOIN  following_count  ON msg.uid = following_count.follower_uid
    GROUP BY  msg.id
    HAVING  created_at > '0'
      AND  category LIKE '%%%'
      AND  msg.uid LIKE '%'
      AND  msg.application LIKE 'demo'
      AND  isLiked='1'
      AND  msg.id <= '999999'
      AND  isVoilation <= '1'
    ORDER BY  msg.id DESC
    LIMIT  10 OFFSET 0
```

This will take more than 8 seconds where my data is about 20k rows per table.
But if I replace `isLiked='1'` with `isLiked='%'` it will execute within 1 second (60 - 70 ms) which is 1000 times faster. So what the mistake I am doing?

UPDATE:
After moving conditions from having clause to where clause, i am getting responce in 2 seconds.
Here is updated query:

```
SELECT  msg.id, CONTENTS, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(msg.created_at) 'created_at',
        category, msg.`uid`,name, user_name, profile_pic, STATUS,
        isNotificationOn, onesignal_id, email, gender, phone,
        users.id userId, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(users.createdAt) 'createdAt',
        ( SELECT  COUNT(1)
            FROM  message_likes
            WHERE  uid = 'CqITnqfe5iZHT8x74zYxuEwzGMY2'
              AND  message_id = msg.id
        ) AS isLiked, 
        ( SELECT  COUNT(*)
            FROM  follower_list
            WHERE  follower_uid = 'CqITnqfe5iZHT8x74zYxuEwzGMY2'
              AND  following_uid = msg.uid) AS isFollowing,
        COUNT(DISTINCT share.uid) + msg.shares 'shares',
        COUNT(DISTINCT likes.uid) 'likes',
        msg.`application`,
        `isModified`, `modificationReason`, `isVoilation`, `voilationReason`,
        `followers_count`, `following_count`
    FROM  user_messages msg
    JOIN  users  ON msg.uid = users.uid
    LEFT JOIN  message_shares SHARE  ON msg.id = share.message_id
    left JOIN  message_likes likes   ON msg.id = likes.message_id 
    LEFT JOIN  followers_count  ON msg.uid = followers_count.following_uid
    LEFT JOIN  following_count  ON msg.uid = following_count.follower_uid
    WHERE category LIKE '%'
      AND  msg.uid like '%'
      AND  msg.application = 'shayari'
      AND  msg.id <= '999999'
      AND  isVoilation <= '1'
    GROUP BY  msg.id HAVING isLiked=1
     ORDER BY likes.created_at desc
```

Now the glitch is if i remove `order by` clause it will execute in few milliseconds and with `order by` clause it is taking about 2-3 seconds. 
Here is explain query:

[image: EXPLAIN SELECT]

Comment: Do you have an index on isLiked? If it's set to %, then the optimiser may realise that it doesn't have  to bother to do any searching/scanning and just returns a result, but it you have a value specified ('1'), then the optimiser has to perform a search/scan!

Comment: We need to see `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and `EXPLAIN SELECT ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be more suggestions, but these should help performance some...

```
        WHERE  uid = '006GA968vpb0O62xaOpKLuhR1cC3'
          AND  message_id = msg.id
```

Presumably, you have `PRIMARY KEY(uid, message_id)` ?

```
        WHERE  follower_uid = '006GA968vpb0O62xaOpKLuhR1cC3'
          AND  following_uid = msg.uid) AS isFollowing,
```

Some kind of index with both `follower_uid` and `following_uid`?

`WHERE` is done while gathering rows; `HAVING` is done after all the rows are gathered.  That is, `WHERE` is more efficient.  However, `HAVING` is required when working with aggregates; but you don't have such.

Don't include unnecessary things like `foo LIKE '%'`.  Instead, build the query without it.

Discourage users from providing `LIKEs` with leading wildcards.

`message_likes` -- Don't `COUNT` something and then just check for 0 or 1.  Instead, use `EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM .. WHERE .. )` -- and this can be put directly in the `WHERE` (unless you also need to fetch the value).

"number = string" -- Avoid mixing numeric and non-numeric.  In some situations, it requires all rows to be dynamically changed from a string to a number before checking.

("voilation" - check spelling)

How much data?  What is the setting of `innodb_buffer_pool_size`?  How much RAM?

`created_at > '0'` -- Huh?  When you upgrade, beware of "zero dates".  Consider changing to `NULL` instead of 0.

Comment: Thank you so much. By replacing having with where and using EXIST () solved my problem, Now it's taking less than 1 second. Regarding "foo LIKE '%' and created_at > '0'" those data will come dynamically from the server according to request so I placed conditions. Data is something 50k+ rows in every table which increases daily. RAM is 8gb of server and innodb_buffer_pool_size is 1G

Comment: @shivajibhosale - If there are no other applications on that server, make the buffer_pool 4G when the data gets too big to fit in the 1G.

Comment: Yes I changed to 4G. Update: Exist clause not giving expected output in every situation so I reverted it. So now its taking 2seconds to execute the query, and if I remove order by clause it is taking few milliseconds. I am updating the question so please check.

Comment: @shivajibhosale - Before I tackle things, let's discuss `isLiked`.  Is that effectively a true/false value?  Or can `isLiked` be `>= 2`?

Comment: isLiked is kind of true or false it returns 0 or 1.

Comment: @shivajibhosale - Then you don't need `COUNT`.  `EXISTS` is a better option.  `LEFT JOIN` would also work, but would give `1` or `NULL`.  `COALESCE()` can turn `NULL` into `0`.